# run a docker X11 application on macos

Tags: macos, docker

I'm trying to connect `opencv` to a external display in the macos host via docker.
I'm using xquartz and socat:

```sh
open -a XQuartz
socat TCP-LISTEN:6000,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:\"$DISPLAY\"
```

socat it's listening correctly:

```sh
ip-192-168-1-168:workoutdj loretoparisi$ lsof -i TCP:6000
COMMAND   PID         USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
socat   40381 loretoparisi    5u  IPv4 0x9d69a8efeca8e83f      0t0  TCP *:6000 (LISTEN)
```

Then (running in a different window) I have tried different approach to connect the display to docker:

```sh
docker run  -e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0 --rm -it -v $(pwd):/app facemaskdetect bash
$ python facemaskdetect/detector.py -i examples/example_01.png -o cam
[INFO] computing face detections...
No protocol specified
: cannot connect to X server host.docker.internal:0
```

or:

```sh
docker run  -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --rm -it -v $(pwd):/app facemaskdetect bash
$ python facemaskdetect/detector.py -i examples/example_01.png -o cam
[INFO] computing face detections...
: cannot connect to X server /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.qIcIi1ayqO/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

I have also tried [the](https://techsparx.com/software-development/docker/display-x11-apps.html) following via `xhost`:

```sh
export IP=$(ifconfig en0 | grep inet | awk '$1=="inet" {print $2}')
xhost +$IP
xhost +local:docker
docker run --rm -it -e DISPLAY=$IP:0 -e XAUTHORITY=/.Xauthority --net host -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v ~/.Xauthority:/.Xauthority  -v $(pwd):/app facemaskdetect bash
$ python facemaskdetect/detector.py -i examples/example_01.png -o cam
[INFO] computing face detections...
: cannot connect to X server :0
```

The referred project is [here](https://github.com/loretoparisi/facemaskdetect), more on this issue [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8710).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since method two uses $IP you can bind that to socat to access the X11 display.
`socat TCP-LISTEN:6000,bind=$IP,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:\"$DISPLAY\"`